# How to check if Tencent(Weibo) app is installed on Android or not programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to detect if Tencent(Weibo) app is installed on Android or not programmatically.

Here is the code I am using:

boolean installed_tweibo = appInstalledOrNot("com.tencent.weibo");

```
    if(installed_tweibo) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, Main1Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();               
    }

    private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean app_installed = false;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            app_installed = true;
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            app_installed = false;
        }
        return app_installed;
    }
```

But "com.tencent.weibo" is incorrect.

I want to know correct package name of Tencent(weibo) app.

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean installed_tweibo = appInstalledOrNot("com.tencent.WBlog");
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct weibo package name is  "com.sina.weibo".

```
public static boolean openApp(Context context, String packageName) {
    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if (i == null) {
        return false;
        //throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
    }
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    context.startActivity(i);
    return true;
}
```

Put in the package name and perform checking and it will open weibo if you installed weibo.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user has the app installed by using this function:

```
public boolean isPackageInstalled(String application) {
    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(application, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So in your Activity, you would simply call:

```
boolean isWeiboInstalled = isPackageInstalled("com.tencent.weibo");
```